# My cat behaves very strange and apathetic and doesn't eat

Tags: cats, health

We have a cat, Gato who went away five days ago and returned two days ago (which is a very long time for a cat as they return at least once per day when they get food).

After returning back he just slept the whole day, didn't eat and all in all looked very "depressed". We thought he just needed some sleep as he was walking very long. But he didn't stop and he didn't sleep anyway. He is just sitting there next to the water, looking into it and doing nothing. Yesterday he almost fell into the water, he can't walk on straight lines sometimes and he doesn't eat.

He doesn't look sick, his eyes are normal, his fur is a little bit messy (probably from his adventure) but he doesn't look good either.

So what could be wrong with him and how can I help him?

I already asked my parents to take him to the vet but they don't want to and say that everything's ok with him. What should I do?

Comment: if a cat stop eating for more than 24 hours it is an emergency,so take the cat to a vet right now.the way you describe the cats behaviour makes me think your cat is seriously ill so you need to take it to a vet as soon as possible as in  right now.

Comment: Not just the lack of eating, but not able to walk in straight lines and lack of coordination are VERY bad signs. Please take your cat to the vet ASAP.

Comment: `which is a very long time for a cat as they return at least once per day when they get food` While common, that is not a given. There are cats who sometimes go on longer excursions. It depends on how able they are to hunt, how much there is to hunt, and the weather.

Comment: Do you know if your cat was ever vaccinated for panleukopenia (aka feline distemper)? This is usually done as a part of the "FVRC**P**" vaccination given to cats. Your description of his behavior at his water reminds me of one of the common symptoms.

Answer (score 8):

**Vet - now!!**

As trond hansen says in their comment any cat not eating for >24hrs is vet-worthy. You add in the difficulty walking, general lethargy and nearly falling into his water and this all sounds potentially quite serious.

Comment: Ok, my parents didn't get him to the vet until today but he eats at the moment. I hope he's getting better. If not I will somehow try to force my parents. Now that I look at him he may have problems eating but at least he eats.

Comment: The fact that he's eating is a good sign but I'd still be pushing to get him seen by a vet ASAP. Hope he's okay!